# FilterAggregation don't work as expect

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I am trying to combine the filters for a FilterAggregation. Here the example:

```
$agg = new Elastica\Aggregation\Filters('size');

$filter1 = new Elastica\Query\Terms();       
$filter1->setTerms('color', $color);

$filter2 = new Elastica\Query\Terms();
$filter2->setTerms('material', $material);

$agg->addFilter($filter1);
$agg->addFilter($filter2);
```

The Problem here, ElasticSearch don't combine the filter and give me an array with 2 elements, where each filter is aggregated but not the aggregation from both filter with AND.

How to make the AND between the filter?

Thanks

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour of `Filters-Aggergation` a per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html)

> Defines a multi bucket aggregations where each bucket is associated
>   with a filter. Each bucket will collect all documents that match its
>   associated filter.

If you wanted an `AND` of two filters you could use  [aggregation-filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) along with [bool-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Example :

```
$agg = new Elastica\Aggregation\Filter('size');

$filter1 = new Elastica\Query\Terms();       
$filter1->setTerms('color', $color);  
$filter2 = new Elastica\Query\Terms();    
$filter2->setTerms('material',$material);

$boolQuery = new Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();
$boolQuery->addFilter($filter1);  
$boolQuery->addFilter($filter2);

$agg->setFilter($boolQuery);
```